# React Native Function Binding (Buttons)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I wonder if anyone could possibly help me understand the issues and implications with React Native binding.

We have built a client app that has several views and a side nav - all of which use this style syntax for events:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.removephoto(key)}>
```

Is this the incorrect method with the potential for memory leaks, and should I use binding ie -

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.removephoto.bind(this, key)}>
```

Is binding in the incorrect way something to add to the worry list with major implications - or is it just best practice!?

I've read a few articles - but most are clear as mud - so i'd appreciate some plain english explanations from one of you experts please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not really an expert but here's a few things to consider:

The component lifecycle can be found in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

The point to keep in mind is that the render method is called every time the component needs to be rendered. This will cause all child components to re-receive props and trigger their update lifecycle methods.

In your current code both the lambda function and bind will create a new function object. This is usually not a problem as it's done very fast.

Where it does cause a problem is when you're using `shouldComponentUpdate` to compare prop objects or are using the built-in HOCs like `PureComponent` (for class components) or `React.memo` for function components. If you are using these components then passing them a lambda or a bound method which will cause them to re-render every time anyway.

In your particular case if `TouchableOpacity` is a `PureComponent` then you should not pass it an inline lambda or an inline bound function.

If you are using a class component you should instead do:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.removephoto.bind(this);
    }

    removephoto(key) {
      //body
    }

    render() {
        return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.removephoto}>;
    }

}
```

This will ensure that you always use the same function object instance.

However you do not need to do this if `TouchableOpacity` is not a pure component and if it does not pass the function down to a child pure component.